# JXBrowser ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, swing, gradle, build.gradle, jxbrowser

I've problem with JXBrowser license file. I've followed https://jxbrowser-support.teamdev.com/docs/quickstart/gradle-config.html official guide to use with Gradle and this is my current build.Gradle

Build seem normal and no any error.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src'
        }
    }

    test {
        java {
            srcDir 'test'
        }
    }
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'main.Main'
    }
}

version '1.0'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url = 'http://maven.teamdev.com/repository/products' }
}

ext {
    jxBrowserVersion = '6.22'
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.2.5'
    compile "com.teamdev.jxbrowser:jxbrowser-cross-platform:${jxBrowserVersion}"
    compile 'com.maxmind.geoip2:geoip2:2.12.0'

    compile files("$rootDir/license.jar")

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

Error happens when it run I'm not sure my build.Gradle is wrong or something here is error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/teamdev/jxbrowser/chromium/PermissionHandler
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.PermissionHandler
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you see this exception when you run your Java application through an executable JAR file.

This exception indicates that you didn't include JxBrowser JAR files into your application class path. I see that you include JxBrowser JAR files as compile dependencies into your `build.gradle`. It's OK during build, but not for production.

Please make sure that you add JxBrowser JAR files into the classpath of your application. For example, you can [download](https://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser) the required JAR files, put them into some directory, and configure the `Class-Path` attribute in your JAR file as show in the Oracle's [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html).

Or you can use the [Gradle plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) that includes all dependencies into a single fat JAR. In this case you don't need to configure Java app classpath.

Comment: for now
`-- Product name: JxBrowser
-- Licensed version: 6.x
-- Licensed to: 
-- License type: Evaluation
-- Generation date: Nov 17, 2018
-- Expiration date: Dec 17, 2018
-- License info: Single-user license
-- Current date: Nov 19, 2018
JxBrowser license valid.
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError`

License seem work but still Initialize Error  I just use 
`// Init web browser
    Browser browser = new Browser();
    BrowserView view = new BrowserView(browser);
`

Comment: I forget another thing is license.jar is at project root

Answer (score 0):

Now it's work using JDK & JRE < 10